# Repeating an array for every row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have an inventory program that contains a lot of data on a single row. I'm attempting to combine that data in using a formula to create sub-items from the primary item. So, essentially, for each row on my sheet I want to create X number of inventory items. The output is arranged in such a manner that my inventory software can import it.

This is the code that I've come up with so far to do that:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",D4&""&BS4:DT4, )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))+1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",E4&" - "&BS4:DT4&"", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",E4&" - "&BS4:DT4&" - "&F4&"", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"","0", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"","310", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"","", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",E4&" - "&BS4:DT4&" - "&F4&"", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",BS4:DT4, )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))+3, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"","201", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0),FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"","Tax on Sales - SK GST Only", )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))-1, 3)=0)})`

Here is the essential formula without the repeating elements:

`FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(BS4:DT4<>"",D4&""&BS4:DT4, )),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(BS4:DT4)))+1, 3)=0)`

What I can't figure out is how to get this formula to work across every row in the spreadsheet. Filters within filters with arrays? My poor head!

Currently this formula evaluates row 4, and expands it X number of times. I need it to evaluate all rows. I also need it to have two TRUE or FALSE checks in it to determine if the particular row should be included in the output.

Here's a link the the actual spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ds1jWjYgknZBli9mXhP_64gNsghCPTsyYqVli8lVZLA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think I could help if you shared a sample sheet. Preferably editable so I can demo and test ideas with your input.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Does this work?: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ds1jWjYgknZBli9mXhP_64gNsghCPTsyYqVli8lVZLA/edit?usp=sharing